# Transparent cancel editing button in chat

Tags: bug, chat, edits

While trying to edit a message in chat, I thought for some reason the 'cancel editing' button was disabled since it showed up transparent.

However, apparently it is just a bug in the animation where the button fades in/out while traversing to message history using the up and down keys.

I'm using Chrome Version 22.0.1229.94 m.

[image: Transparent button]