# Chat "cancel editing" button fades out if put in the sun for too long

Tags: bug, chat, design

[image]

On a single chat window, if I use the keyboard shortcut to edit a message, then hit "cancel editing" and repeat, the "cancel editing" button starts fading out at each iteration.

This is a bit confusing if you're in the chatroom for a while and have already cancelled editing a couple of times. The button eventually disappears — it works, but is invisible so it seems as if you can't cancel the edit.

Comment: I think same cause as [this old bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154915/transparent-cancel-editing-button-in-chat), not sure enough to mark as dupe though.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It used to be that the button was _always_ invisible, I think.

Comment: Nope, see [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211277/152859) and the commments, especially by Tim.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Ah, but that's still different. Tim's message is about up-arrow editing an older message. That works fine now, I think.